Can I alter maven-surefire-plugin's behaviur without explicitly listing the plugin in my pom.xml?
Although I do not explicitly include the maven-surefire-plugin in my pom.xml, my tests are nonetheless being duly run:
...
[INFO] --- surefire:3.2.5:test (default-test) @ myproject---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.MyUtilsTest
...

This suits me fine except, for some reason, the test-names aren't printed -- neither the names of the test-methods in MyUtilsTest, nor the more descriptive names I added using the @DisplayName decorators. Maybe, they would've shown up in Eclipse or some other GUI, but I'm using command-line...
Apparently, maven-surefire-plugin needs to be told to display test-names, but I loath adding the plugin explicitly, because I like my pom.xml lean (and don't want yet another plugin-version to chase later).
Perhaps, the plugin's behavior can be affected by setting something inside <properties>? Or with some other decorator?
